# How to add target="_blank" into this code

Tags: php, wordpress

**PHP**

```
<p class="postmeta">
    <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
        <?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'gridster' ) );
            if ( $categories_list && gridster_categorized_blog() ) :
        ?>
            <?php printf( __( '%1$s', 'gridster' ), $categories_list ); ?>
        <?php endif; // End if categories ?>


    <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?>
</p>
```

**It produces this HTML:**

```
<p class="postmeta">
    <a href="http://myurl.com/category/blahblah/" title="View all posts in blahblah" rel="category tag">blahblah</a>            
</p>
```

I tried reading the wordpress codex but I really couldn't figure out how to add `target="_blank"` into the `a` tag. I'm trying to add that so that the link will open in a new tab.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check the function itself

Comment: you need to do changes in function get_the_category_list()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this filter to apply `_blank` to `get_the_category_list()`, because `get_the_category_list()` runs it output through the filter `the_category`

```
add_filter('the_category', 'wp55_the_category');
function wp55_the_category($cat_list) {
    return str_ireplace('<a', '<a target="_blank"', $cat_list);
}
```

add this in your `functions.php` file. For more information take a look on these filters http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Database_Reads_3

Answer (score 0):

`get the category list` is meant to be very basic. You have 3 choices:

1) change that function to something else such as using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories

2) parse the returned $categories_list using PHP

3) use some javascript - let's say you have jquery in your them then you could just add this somewhere:

```
jQuery.ready(function() {
 jQuery('.postmeta a').attr('target','_blank');
});
```